# css pseudoclass selector

Tags: css, pseudo-class, css-selectors

I want to select the second div in my markup with css using **:nth-child** but I cannot make it work.

I have this markup generated by a plugin:

```
<div class="single-container">
                <div class="toggle-default">
                    <div class="toggle">
                    <div class="toggle_title toggle_active">FIRST</div>
                    <div class="toggle_content" style="display:block;">Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</div></div>

                    </div>

    <div class="toggle-default">
                    <div class="toggle">
                    <div class="toggle_title toggle_active">SECOND </div>
                    <div class="toggle_content" style="display:block;">Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</div></div>

                    </div>



    <div class="toggle-default">
                    <div class="toggle">
                    <div class="toggle_title toggle_active">THIRD </div>
                    <div class="toggle_content" style="display:block;">Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</div></div>

                    </div>


    </div>
```

I've tried this : `.toggle-deafult .toggle:nth-child(2) { background:red; }` and this `.toggle div:nth-child(2)` but it's not working.

Can someone help me with this ?

Thank you !

LATER EDIT: I've modified the markup, this is what I need to modify : `<div class="toggle_title toggle_active">SECOND </div>`

Comment: If you want the 2nd `.toggle-default` to be red, use `.toggle-default:nth-child(2) { background:red; }`. Note: you have spelt _default_ incorrectly in the question.

Comment: Do yo mean `.toggle-default .toggle :nth-child(2)` (mind the space and the default typo)? I'm not clear which one you want colored. With the space, you'll target the second child of your div.toggle.

Comment: Which _"second div"_ do you want red. The 2nd `.toggle-default` or 2nd div inside a `.toggle-default`?

Comment: What does "second div in my markup" mean exactly? Are you in [Depth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [Breadth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)?

Comment: I've modified the markup, I hope now it's clear, tried also your suggestions but still not work.

Comment: this is what I need to modify : <div class="toggle_title toggle_active">SECOND </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.toggle-default:nth-child(2) .toggle_title{ background:#f00;}
```

It is the second one which you want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

You need `.toggle-default:nth-of-type(2n) { color: red; }` (note the *2n*).

Answer (score 0):

```
.toggle-default:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my markup with the exact div which I need to modify